# I need to get time difference in days between two date rows of the same record history in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server

I have table (called `STAT`) for tracking work order status change, like this:

```
| WORKNUM    | STATUS    | CHANGE_DATE             |
+------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| WO-1057004 | APPROVED  | 2018-05-25 05:53:34.157 |
| WO-1057004 | COMPLETED | 2018-06-13 06:45:4O.244 |
| WO-1057004 | REVIEWED  | 2018-07-05 03:53:35.231 |
```

I need to find time in days it took from 'COMPLETED' status to 'REVIEWED' status, for the same work order - i.e. the difference in `CHANGE_DATE` between these two statuses in days.

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

I don’t know where to begin, but I am looking for something like this:

```
| WORKNUM    | STATUS    | CHANGE_DATE             | TIME_TAKEN |
+------------+-----------+-------------------------+------------+
| WO-1057004 | APPROVED  | 2018-05-25 05:53:34.157 |     0      |
| WO-1057004 | COMPLETED | 2018-06-13 06:45:4O.244 |    19      |
| WO-1057004 | REVIEWED  | 2018-07-05 03:53:35.231 |    22      |
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually your description of the problem is wrong. What you appear to want in the sample output is the number of days between successive transitions. Look up `lag()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    select worknum,[status],change_date,
CASE
    WHEN [status]='COMPLETED' THEN 
        DATEDIFF(day, change_date, (select top 1 change_date from stat as stat_approved where stat_approved.[status]='APPROVED' and stat_approved.worknum=stat.worknum))
    WHEN [status]='APPROVED' THEN 
        DATEDIFF(day, change_date, (select top 1 change_date from stat as stat_completed where stat_completed.[status]='COMPLETED' and stat_completed.worknum=stat.worknum))    
    ELSE 0
END as TIME_TAKEN
from stat
```

Answer (score 0):

One way, which is at least easy to read and portable, is:

```
select
    STAT.WORKNUM,
    STATUS,
    CHANGE_DATE,
    DATEDIFF(day, APPROVED_DATE, CHANGE_DATE) as TIME_TAKEN
from STAT
join (
    select WORKNUM, CHANGE_DATE as APPROVED_DATE
    from STAT
    where STATUS = 'APPROVED'
) APPROVED_DATES on APPROVED_DATES.WORKNUM = STAT.WORKNUM
```

The subquery returns (not surprisingly, given its alias) all the approved dates. Every row is joined to that to allow the difference to be calculated.

Although there are more efficient ways of retrieving the data (using windowing functions), readability and portability is important too. This query is understandable, and thus maintainable, and (unlike the SQL Server windowing functions) will work with practically every database out there, especially mocked ones so you can unit test it without an actual database present.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,
case when status='APPROVED' then 0 when status='COMPLETED' then 
datediff(day,(select change_date from STAT where status='APPROVED'),(select change_date from STAT where status='COMPLETED')) 
when status='REVIEWED' then 
datediff(day,(select change_date from STAT where status='COMPLETED'),(select change_date from STAT where status='REVIEWED')) 
end NoOfDays
FROM STAT
```

[image]